# what is the difference between a = x and a=x[:] in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn Python. Can someone please help me understand the difference between following two:
 a = x vs a=x[:]

Comment: hint: what does `a.slice(0)` do in javascript?

Comment: Impossible to tell unless you say what `a` is. For tuples both are the same thing

Comment: @JBernardo I think you mean "[...] what `x` is". That is true, though for most well behaved types (including tuples, that a shallow copy does nothing is just an optimization) its behaviour is identical to the list case, modulo fooling around with `id()`/`is`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to explain:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> a = x
>>> # a is reference to x - a[0] and x[0] are same variable
>>> a[0] = 4 # same as x[0]...
>>> print x # proof
[4, 2, 3]
>>> a = x[:] # a is copy of x
>>> a[2] = 5 # a[2] is not x[2]
>>> print x
[4, 2, 3]
>>> print a
[4, 2, 5]
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

`a = x` creates a reference:

```
a = [2]
x = a
print id(a)
print id(x)
```

Produces:

```
39727240
39727240
```

So if you alter `a` then `x` would change too because they are the same objects

**Whereas**

`a = x[:]` creates a new object

```
a = [2]
x = a[:]
print id(a)
print id(x)
```

Produces:

```
41331528
39722056
```

But over here changing `a` doesn't alter `x` because they are different objects

Comment: Only for lists (OP did not specify the object).

Comment: @JBernardo python is OP so even a list is a object in python

Comment: I mean, e.g. for tuples this is not true

Comment: @JBernardo There's no way to mutate tuples to begin with, so there wouldn't be any point to making a copy. Yes different underlying implementation but it gives you the same results anyhow (apart from id(), true)

Answer (score 2):

```
In [648]: b = a

In [649]: b[0] = 2

In [650]: a  
Out[650]: [2]  <- a also changed

In [651]: b = a[:] <- Creating new object

In [652]: b[0] = 3

In [653]: b  
Out[653]: [3]

In [654]: a  
Out[654]: [2] <- a did not change
```